# Better way to re-write this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, TableA and TableBNew. Here is the link for the image that shows the table and its content:

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about code optimization and should be asked at [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1):

One of the optimization rules is:
 - try to reduce the amount of manipulated data as much as you can.

This is a bit more efficient but it's not shorter.

The difference here is that I do the join only on the years I need (a.k.a: filter then join), instead of joining everything and filtering later.

```
SELECT AB.PART_TYPE, BC.AVG_2012_PRICE
FROM (SELECT TableA.partName AS PART_TYPE, AVG(TableBNew.price) AS AVG_price_2011 
FROM TableA 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM TableBNew  WHERE TableBNew.year=2011)
ON TableA.partID = TableBNew.partID

GROUP BY TableA.partName 
HAVING AVG(TableBNew.price) < 1000) AB

INNER JOIN

(SELECT TableA.partName AS PART_TYPE, AVG(TableBNew.price) AS AVG_price_2012 FROM TableA INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM TableBNew WHERE TableBNEw.year=2012) ON
TableA.partID = TableBNew.partID
GROUP BY TableA.partName) BC
ON AB.PART_TYPE=BC.PART_TYPE
```

Comment: Using subqueries in the `FROM` clause is unnecessary in most databases and often detrimental in MySQL.  MySQL has a tendency to materialize subqueries, which prevents the use of indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems way over complicated.  You can simplify it using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT b.PartName,
       AVG(CASE WHEN n.year = 2012 THEN n.price END) AS AVG_price_2012 
FROM TableA a JOIN
     TableBNew n
     ON a.PartID = n.PartId
WHERE n.year IN (2011, 2012)
GROUP BY a.partName 
HAVING AVG(CASE WHEN n.year = 2011 THEN n.price END) < 1000;
```

I am not sure why you are renaming `PartName` to `PartType`.  That doesn't seem useful.